# WordPress how to split month and day date into two pieces

Tags: wordpress, date, split

How can I split the "month" and "day" date into two seperate pieces so I can place them under each other like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the current day you can:

```
echo date('d');
```

and for current month:

```
echo date('m');
```

in a short textual representation of a month, three letters:

```
echo date('M');
```

But if you have the date already in a string variable you can for day:

```
echo date('d',strtotime('11/26/2011'));
```

and for month:

```
echo date('M',strtotime('11/26/2011'));
```

For complete references of the functions:

- [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: The echo date('F'); for the month and the echo date('j'); for the day works like a charm, thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="month"><?php echo get_the_date('M'); ?></p>
<p class="day"><?php echo get_the_date('d'); ?></p>
```